# Python, what is the most efficient way to add values to a vector at a random indexes?

Tags: python, performance

I am trying to find the best way to execute the following code. in practice i would be adding specific values at specific indices, not adding 1.

```
#this is a simplified code for illustration purpose and must not be optimized

from random import randint, random
from numpy import zeros

n = 10
N = 1000

indicies = [randint(0, n-1) for p in range(0, N)]
values = [random.random() for p in range(0, N)]
x = zeros(n)
y = zeros(n)



#the issue is here. I want to do this as efficiently as possible :
for i in range(N):
    x[indicies[i]]+= values[i]

#I tried this but it does not work.
y[indicies]+= values


print(x)
print(y)
```

here is what i get by substituting the values vector by a vector of ones :

```
#correct result
[103.  95. 109. 113.  79. 105.  90.  99. 105. 102.]
#failed attempt to go faster
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
```

I want to get x.
Obviously my attempt with y has failed.

For those interested, i am computing conditional expectations in Monte Carlo, projecting values on a (time x space) grid. So for 252 time steps of my stochastic process and 2^20 MC paths, i would be doing 250 *  2 million operations. In practice the diffusion of the process is done by batches of 2^10 MC paths and efficiently vectorized but when i am projecting, i have not found a way to do it other than time step by time step and path by path.

This step of the algorithm take up 98% of the computation time so i must be doing something wrong.

Thanks for your help.

Edit :

Given the first answers i must clarify my issue. I already have a vector of indexes, and a vector of values. The issue is not with generating random numbers. I am looking for an efficient way to increment my target vector :

```
for i in range(N):
    target[indexes[i]]+=values[i]
```

Edit 2 :

The algorithm works, here is an illustration of what i get. it is just too slow :

[look at it, it is quite cool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDqTt.png)

Comment: x and y will be the same value.  Why not build a random list of 1000 and accumulate it for each element of x and y?

Comment: x and y should give the same result. x is the correct result. y is an attempt to do it faster, a failed attemp

Answer (score 0):

First, since you're using `numpy`, use `np.random.randint` for `x`:

```py
x = np.random.randint(0, n-1, N)
```

Then to add random values to `x`, just use another random vector and add it to `x`:

```py
x + np.random.randint(low, high, N)
```

RE: edit 2.

Since you seem dead set on this approach, here's a possible solution, assuming I'm understanding you correctly:

```py
>>> indices = [0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> values = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> for idx in set(indices):
...     values[idx] += indices.count(idx)
...
>>> values
[3, 2, 1, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Are you attempting to increment `x` by `1` at random indices or do you have SPECIFIC indices where this increment should happen? It's not really clear what you're asking. Adding a vector of random values to `x` using `+=` would "increment" your vector `x` element-wise.

Comment: Also, your OP says you want to add random values, but your edit says you want to increment (which implies `+= 1`). Which is it?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "a vector of indexes"? @Didobarre

Comment: Sorry, i tried to express it as clearly as possible. Yes, I have specific indices where specific increments should happen. specifically 2^10 indices ranging randomly from 0 to 500, with 2^10 increments ( one for each index )

Comment: @Didobarre so you have a vector of indexes where an increment should happen, and a SEPARATE vector of the increments themselves? Why? This is horribly inefficient. Please edit the OP with an explicit example of what you start with, and what you expect as output.

Comment: Edited. hope it is clearer. yes i have a vector of indexes and a separate vector of increments. I used +1 increments in my example to illustrate that my code for y only increments each index once for a reason i don't really understand. basically it is supposed to count the number of 0, 1, 2 and so on but again it is just to illustrate.

Comment: This is a really terrible approach. Why is the order of your indices randomized? Why not just increment each element in `values` ONCE? If your index vector has multiple entries for a specific index, say `indices = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1]` and you're incrementing values based on the count of indices... my god, that's just so convoluted... I don't see why you're constrained to this approach. I HIGHLY recommend instead using a single vector to represent EACH index's specific increment, where if any element does NOT get incremented, the value at that index is 0.

Comment: well i computing a conditional expectation so i basically i diffuse a random process, compute a function of the process and i map it to a grid of my choice of the level of my process at a given time step. But i simultaniously do that for each time steps and each possible value of the process. So the process at time t lands at a value x and i project the function of my process on the closest point to x value on my grid.

Comment: still not getting me. I'm sorry if my english is not that good. count would work for adding 1, not for adding specific values.

Comment: I added an illustration of my results to demonstrate that i have good reason to proceed this way, and indeed i end up with a vector of indices, a vector of values and i have to increment my target vector at index indices[i] with values[i].

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.random.randint` ([docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html)).

How you might use it:

```
n = 10
N = 1000
z = np.random.randint(0, N, size=n)
```

output: z = [292 237 838 860 590 933  29 154 168 606]

Answer (score 0):

accumulate 1000 random choices

```
n = 10
N = 1000

indice = [random.randint(0, n-1) for p in range(0, N)]
values = [random.random() for p in range(0, N)]

x = zeros(n)
y = zeros(n)

def GetRandomChoice():
    index=random.choice(indice)
    value=values[index]
    return index,value

for i in range(N):
    index,value=GetRandomChoice()
    x[index]+= value
    index,value=GetRandomChoice()
    y[index]+= value

print(x,y)
output:
[  4.98649477  13.4498052  100.04144429  77.06294844  
   80.52940448 9.50733693  41.0324075   22.74005395  
   48.31112763  83.95712759]
[  5.24090776  14.72399728  81.06806692  92.87073274  
   75.9711363  8.36970687  37.00243891  18.15536565  
   58.40599011 116.76795906]
```

Comment: You are missunderstanding me. indices and values have already been computed by a complex algorithm ( in my example i chose them at random because it is similar to what would happen in the real algorithm ). what i want to do is what i described. target is a vector of a given size ( here 10 ) and indices is a vector of indices each ranging from 0 to 9. i want to do target[indices[i]] += values[i], for all i in range(N = 1000). this step is unreasonably time consuming and i am wondering if it is possible to do it differently and more efficiently.

Comment: use y=x.copy()   if you want an exact copy of x